# Free variable in GHCi debugger

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

In the GHC user manual [GHCI debugger](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/ghci-debugger.html#breakpoints) section, it is stated:

> GHCi has provided bindings for the free variables of the expression on which the breakpoint was placed (**a, left, right**), and additionally a binding for the result of the expression (**_result**).

Thus, the free variables here are **a, left, right**.

How come the variable **as** is *not* a free variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The breakpoint was placed at line two which reads

```
qsort (a:as) = qsort left ++ [a] ++ qsort right
```

but the breakpoint will be on the expression on the right of the `=`, as it says:

```
Breakpoint 0 activated at qsort.hs:2:15-46
```

so that's characters 15-46 - the right hand side. `as` doesn't appear on the right hand side, so that's why it's not a free variable of that expression.